# Very simple static website with google analytics. How to make it GDPR compliant?

Tags: html, cookies, google-analytics, gdprconsentform

There is a very simple static website for a commerce. That website only shows information. It haves google analytics to count visits with the default GA script placed in :

```
<head>
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
</head>
```

As you can see, is the default script that google gives you for a simple integration of GA in your website, and it's placed in the default place (header).

**Now it haves a lower bar displaying this:**

> This website uses 'cookies' for your navigation. By using our services you accept their use.
> If you want to restrict the use of cookies, click on More information.

That bar haves two buttons, "accept" and "More information". Accept simply hides the bar forever, and more information displays the legal info of the commerce and tells the users that it is using google analytics to track the visits, and that google analytics uses cookies. Also, tells the user that he can remove the cookies and prevent the website collecting cookies disabling it in the navigator, and gives the user some links with official help about how to disable and remove cookies for a website in four big navigators (firefox, chrome, IE, safari).

Is enough with that to be compliand with **GDPR** in this very simple website which only uses GA to track visits?

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, to be 100% complaint (which is good for all Guarantors) you can inhibit Analytics tracking until the user has given consent to cookies, at which point you start the Analytics tag.

Then there are variants, i.e. with the anonymization of the IP of Google Analytics some guarantors consider the Google Analytics cookie as a technical cookie, so if you always keep it anonymized and if you have no other cookies except technical cookies you could also avoid to show the cookiebar. However, it depends on what the Guarantor you refer to says.

It is a very broad and intricate topic, on the other hand they are legal issues, in any case, in the first case described you are safer, that is by providing Google Analytics only to those who accept cookies.

Comment: if i do that (inhibit Analytics tracking until the user has given consent to cookies), i will not be able to know how many visitors have the site. For a very very simple case like this (static website with only info about a commerce), does exist a simpler way to be safe without calling GA only if the user press accept? (for example, doing some setup in GA console to restrict to only get anonymous data of the numbers of visitors or similar...)

Comment: I'm from spain, so I think my Guarantor should be spanish AEPD.

Comment: I'm not a legal, I don't know spanish law, I know that italian Guarantor said somenthing for which it is clear that with the anonymization of the IP of Google Analytics its cookie may be considered as a technical cookie, so in this case just use anonimyzeIp parameter and GA can also be performed before accepting cookies.

Comment: ok, so I added ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true); into my ga script. Now, should be fine?

Comment: Yes, this will obscure the last part of the user's IP making it anonymous.